# Get a push PAYLOAD, after user tap-on-notification, actually in userNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

In your app delegate

```
import UserNotifications
class AppDelegate: ...  UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
```

If you:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
 didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
 withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    print("notification tapped to open app ....")

    completionHandler()
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
 willPresent notification: UNNotification,
 withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    print("notification arrived while app in foreground!")

    completionHandler(.alert)
}
```

When you

- GET A NOTIFICATION

and indeed the

- user TAPS TO OPEN the notification

then

- your app will open beautifully

and

- indeed, **the functions above will fire perfectly**,

and you will see 'notification tapped to open app ...' on the console.

But in those functions,

how the heck do you get **the actual push PAYLOAD**?

(That is to say the `.data` value ...... or indeed any part of the payload.  For example, if you're using the excellent [github.com/AndrewBarba/apns2](http://github.com/AndrewBarba/apns2) you'd want precisely where it has the example `data: {` ... )

How the heck do you get the notification (payload) in the `UserNotifications` delegate functions?!

Again this is when the user ***has actually opened the app, simply by tapping (ie, "slide, open") on a notification.

I am NOT discussing the difficult issue of waking an app in background (say, to download a file etc).

How the heck do you get the payload?

Comment: `UNNotificationResponse.notification.request.content.userInfo`

Comment: got it, awesome, thanks @mag_zbc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer kindly provided by the crew at npm-apns2

For data like

```
let bn = new BasicNotification(deviceToken, 'Teste', {
  data: {
    name: 'jack',
    street: 'jones'
  } })
```

so ...

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
 didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
 withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
  @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("notification tapped, app opens")
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    let name: String? = userInfo["name"] as! String?
    let street: String? = userInfo["street"] as! String?
    let test3: String? = userInfo["typo"] as! String?
    print("> \(name)")      // optional 'jack'
    print("> \(street)")    // optional 'jones'
    print("> \(test3)")     // nil

    completionHandler()
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
 willPresent notification: UNNotification,
 withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("notification arrived while app in foreground (user has
            not 'tapped on notification' - you get this immediately)")

    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo     // sic

    let name: String? = userInfo["name"] as! String?
    let street: String? = userInfo["street"] as! String?
    let test3: String? = userInfo["typo"] as! String?
    print("> \(name)")      // optional 'jack'
    print("> \(street)")    // optional 'main'
    print("> \(test3)")     // nil

    completionHandler(.alert)
}
```

and that's it.